# Open VS Code from Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio-code

I use both Notepad++ and VS Code, and for easy switching between the two, I have set up a *Run* command in Notepad++ to start VS Code with the current file, and caret position:

```
code -g $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH):$(CURRENT_LINE):$(CURRENT_COLUMN)
```

However, the values for line and column are off by 1, so if in Notepad++ I am on line 2, column 4, I find myself at line 1 column 3 in VS Code.

Apart from writing an intermediate script that adds 1 to both values, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

CMD can't really do arithmetic in one line, so I would use powershell. This command works for me, though it's not much different than writing up a script at this point. I've added line breaks for readability, but it is a one-liner for NP++ Run:

```sh
powershell -command $FILE="""$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""";
$LINE=$(CURRENT_LINE)+1;
$COLUMN=$(CURRENT_COLUMN)+1;
$command = """code -g `"""${FILE}:${LINE}:${COLUMN}`""" """;
Invoke-Expression -command $command
```

Triple quotes since notepad launches programs using `Run`, and variable names in `${foo}` format due to colon characters.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for something *other* than a script.

Comment: @Berend it's still a single NP++ run command like you have in your question. Neither VS Code nor NPP have an option to change their line/character indexes, though both have github issues requesting it